# How to reset the bibliography so the citations in the text look like [number1-numberN]?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm working on a latex template whose link is [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-arkansas-thesis-template/gmndvzdyzjbx). If I have, for example, four successive references in the bibliography (say, numbers 4 to 7), the citation in the text appears like [4,5,6,7], but I want it looks like [4-7]. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: By using citation style "numeric-comp", I think.

Comment: @Plergux How to do?

Comment: You define the style in the preamble (the area between \documentclass{} and \begin{document}): \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}. Note that this uses the biblatex package and not the default bibtex, but by defining the backend as bibtex you can continue using that if you've been using that to compile your references.